# Degree of connectivity of a graph

Tags: java, graph, hashmap, hashset

I'm trying to calculate the degree of each node in a graph. However I'm having trouble because the nodes are part of the node class and I don't know how to convert them to `String`. At least I think that's what's wrong. 
Here's what I've been trying, I have a `Hashset` where I store the nodes and another one for the edges (undirected graph), and I need to get a table with all the degrees that exists followed by the nodes that have those degrees:

```
public void DegreeList () {
    List<Nodes> listnodes = new ArrayList<Nodes>(Node);
    Map <Integer, List<Nodes>> DegreeList = new HashMap<Integer, List<Nodes>>();
    for (Nodes n: Node){
        int degree=0;
        for (Edges e: Edge){
            if (n.equals(e.start)||n.equals(e.end)){
                degree++;
                DegreeList.put(degree,n);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error from Eclipse is for the last line and says:

> The method put(Integer, List) in the type Map> is not applicable for the arguments (int, Nodes).

I'm open to try other approach.

Edit: `Nodes` and `Edges` are classes. `Edge` and `Node` are the `Hashsets` storing the values. (Sorry for any confusion)

Comment: Edit: Is there an easier approach to finding the full degree of the network considering I have both the nodes and the edges stores in hashsets and it's undirected?

Comment: Edit: Nodes and Edges are classes. Edge and Node are the hashsets storing the values. (Sorry for any confusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working Assumptions

It looks from your code as if the type `Nodes` represents a single node, and `Node` represents a `Collection` of nodes. (And that assumption was confirmed by your edit.) Those names seem backwards, but I'm going by what the code is doing with them. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

## The Immediate Question

There are several problems here, but the immediate one is pretty simple: your `Map` expects a value of type `List<Nodes>`, but you're giving it a single instance of `Nodes`. If you can change your `Map` to a Guava `Multimap` then please do so. Otherwise, instead of

```
DegreeList.put(degree, n);
```

you'll need something like

```
List<Nodes> innerList = DegreeList.get(degree);
if (innerList == null) {
    innerList = new ArrayList<Nodes>();
    DegreeList.put(degree, innerList);
}
innerList.add(n);
```

That way there's a `List` associated with each `degree`. You need this because a `Map` can only store one value with each key. If your `Map` was defined like `Map<Integer, Nodes>` then you could only store one node with each distinct degree number. But that doesn't make any sense, does it? Any number of nodes could share the same degree number. So you need a `Map` that associates an `Integer` (representing degree) with a `Collection` of nodes. You seem to be using `List` as your chosen `Collection`. `Set` would probably be better.

Using `Set`, you'd define your `Map` as

```
Map<Integer, Set<Nodes>> degreeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, when it came time to put something into the `Map` you'd do it like this:

```
Set<Nodes> innerSet = degreeMap.get(degree);
if (innerSet == null) {
    innerSet = new HashSet<>();
    degreeMap.put(degree, innerSet);
}
innerSet.add(n);
```

In either case you no longer need your `listNodes` `List`.

## Other Observations

The code above describes how to put something into the `Map`. But we also need to think about *when* to put something into the `Map`. Right now you have code inserting into the `Map` each time there's an edge that matches the node you're evaluating:

```
for (Edges e: Edge){
    if (n.equals(e.start)||n.equals(e.end)){
        degree++;
        DegreeList.put(degree,n); // this shouldn't be here
    }
}
// instead, it belongs here
```

Instead, you should insert into the `Map` only once per node, *after* determining the node's degree:

```
for (Edges e: Edge){
    if (n.equals(e.start)||n.equals(e.end)){
        degree++;
    }
}

// insert into Map here
Set<Nodes> innerSet = degreeMap.get(degree);
if (innerSet == null) {
    innerSet = new HashSet<>();
    degreeMap.put(degree, innerSet);
}
innerSet.add(n);
```

Comment: Thanks Erick, would you mind explaining the innerlList bit? my list "listnodes" is now unused, should I keep it? 
What other problems do you see at first sight?

Comment: Sure, editing now. While I'm doing that, would you mind editing your question to explain the difference between the `Node` and `Nodes` types?

Comment: Of course, I probably need to change the names to make things clearer too

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the explanation. Just one more thing if you don't mind, do I access the values in the same way I would in a HashMap? Like:
     degreeMap.get("4")

Comment: `degreeMap` _is_ a `HashMap`, so yes. Except you don't put quotes around the 4 (you never should have) since it's an `Integer`, not a `String`.

Comment: So, I've been working on the changes, but if I insert the "degreeMap.put(degree, innerSet)" after the for loop, I get an error of "innerSet cannot be resolved into a variable". What's the solution to this?

Comment: Hi @TamaraDominguezPoncelas, sorry, just saw your question from Feb 3. You don't just put the `put()` statement after the `for` loop, you put all of the new code after the `for` loop. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

While Erick's answer is correct, it is not very efficient. If you want to calculate the degree of all nodes in a graph, and you want to store that in a map keyed by degrees, a faster algorithm would be the following:

```
public static Map<Integer, ArrayList<Node>> nodesByDegree(
        Collection<Edge> edges, Collection<Node> nodes) {

    HashMap<Node, Integer> degrees = new HashMap<>();

    // initialize all nodes with 0 degrees
    for (Node n : nodes) {
        degrees.put(n, 0);
    }

    // calculate all degrees at the same time, in a single pass through E
    for (Edge e : edges) {
        degrees.put(e.start, degrees.get(n.start)+1);
        degrees.put(e.end, degrees.get(n.end)+1);
    }

    // transform into multimap
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Node>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Node, Integer> e : degrees) {
        if ( ! result.containsKey(e.getValue()) {
            result.put(e.getValue(), new ArrayList<Node>());
        }
        result.get(e.getValue()).add(e.getKey());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that, in the above code, `edges` is a collection of `Edge`, and `nodes` is a collection of `Node`. This code requires O(|V|) + O(|E|) run-time, which should be much lower than O(|V|) * O(|E|)